# Scanning an entire ip range / subnet for port 80 open?

Tags: centos, port

I need a fast and efficient way to scan an ip range for port 80 open.

So for example if I wanted to scan OVH IP range "46.105.0.0/16" I need it to scan every ip in that range and output a list of every ip with port 80 open.

```
46.105.0.51
46.105.0.72
46.105.0.91
46.105.0.7
46.105.0.15
```

I need to scan multiple subnets and I need it to output to a file.

Edit: I'm also running CentOS on my dedicated box w/ a 1Gbit uplink.

Answer (score 7):

[`nmap` to the rescue!](http://nmap.org/book/man-examples.html):

```
nmap -Pn -p80 --open 46.105.0.0/16
```

...will get you a list of hosts responding on `tcp/80` and corresponding `nmap` output;

- `-Pn`: skips the ping test, as you only care about an open port
- `--open`: returns only the IPs for which your port is open

With a little `awk`ing (and `grep`, cause I'm lazy and not so great at `awk` - could an `awk` master fix this for me?), you can get just the list of IPs:

```
nmap -Pn -p80 --open 46.105.0.0/16 | grep 46.105 | awk '{print  $5}NF == 6{print $6}'
```

`nmap` also has options for outputting to files in specific formats, or you can just `>` to a file:

```
nmap -Pn -p80 --open 46.105.0.0/16 | grep 46.105 | awk '{print  $5}NF == 6{print $6}' > output.txt
```

Comment: I'm getting errors using your commands.


Illegal Argument to -P, use -P0, -PI, -PB, -PE, -PM, -PP, -PA, -PU, -PT, or -PT80 (or whatever number you want for the TCP probe destination port)
QUITTING!

I also need it to be outputted to a .txt file.

Comment: Ok, replace `-Pn` with `-P0`. Outputting to a file should be as simple as adding `> output.txt` to the end of the command.

Comment: Try `nmap -P0 -p80 --open 46.105.0.0/16 | grep 46.105 | awk '{print  $5}NF == 6{print $6}' > output.txt`

Comment: Alright thank you very much admdrew. Working great so far but it exports it like this: Interesting ports on vpsxxxxx.ovh.net (46.105.x.x):
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

How can I get rid of all that useless junk and just have the IP?

Total noob with grep and nmap. Thanks

Comment: What version of nmap do you have (`nmap --version`)? The `--open` flag should only return hosts that are `open`, not `filtered` or `closed`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this post who happens to have no access to nmap, here's a quick and rudimentary way of scanning for port 80 on the network. The only thing needed by this script is ipcalc which is most likely available.

```
#!/bin/bash
# easier to end the script if signal is caught
trap exit 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
# define a function that emulate netcat by opening a port to an ip via file descriptor
netcat() {
        exec 20<>/dev/tcp/${1}/${2}
}

# using ipcalc, get the nwtork address and the broadcast address and make both $NETWORK and $BROADCAST available to the script
export $(ipcalc -b -n $1)

# Convert the NETWORK and BROADCAST from dotted notation to hex
printf -v startHexIP "%0.2x%0.2x%0.2x%0.2x" $(tr '\.' ' ' <<< $NETWORK)
printf -v endHexIP "%0.2x%0.2x%0.2x%0.2x" $(tr '\.' ' ' <<< $BROADCAST)

# computations are done in decimal so we need decimal representation of the BROADCAST address to control the list of IP addresses
printf -v endDecIP "%d" 0x${endHexIP}

# legitimate IP addresses start from NETWORK ADDRESS + 1 and end at BROADCAST ADDRESS - 1
for((i=$(( 0x$startHexIP + 1 )); i<$endDecIP; i++)); do
        # $i is in decimal. we need to convert to hex
        printf -v hexI "%8.8x" $i
        # convert hex to dotted notation.
        printf -v ip "%d.%d.%d.%d" 0x${hexI:0:2} 0x${hexI:2:2} 0x${hexI:4:2} 0x${hexI:6:2}
        if (netcat $ip 80 > /dev/null 2>&1); then
                echo $ip
        fi
done
```

The script can be executed passing just one argument, `<network>/<prefix>`.

Example.

```
./script 192.168.1.5/23
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be done in just 4 lines of script.

Create the script file named "scanall" (just example) 
and copy the code below, it will scan /24 network. (1-254)

```
# SCRIPT NAME: scanall
# USAGE      : scanall SUBNET PORT # put up to 3rd octet
#
# EXAMPLE    : scanall 192.168.1 80
#                       subnet  port

END=254
for i in $(seq 1 $END); do
    netcat -vz -w1 $1.$i $2;
done

# script will put 4th octet starting from 1 to 254 each line of netcat test.
# edit END to 128 if you want ip range 1~128 to be checked which is /25
```

so if I wanted scanall 192.168.1.0/24 to find opened port 22, simply run
(after chmod +x)

```
bash:~$ scanall 192.168.1 22
```

then the result will show

```
192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.2] 22 (ssh): open
192.168.1.2 [192.168.1.2] 22 (ssh): Connection refused
.
.
192.168.1.183 [192.168.1.183] 22 (ssh): Operation timed out
192.168.1.184 [192.168.1.184] 22 (ssh): Connection refused 
192.168.1.185 [192.168.1.185] 22 (ssh) open                
192.168.1.186 [192.168.1.186] 22 (ssh): Operation timed out
192.168.1.187 [192.168.1.187] 22 (ssh): Operation timed out
192.168.1.188 [192.168.1.188] 22 (ssh): Operation timed out
.
.
192.168.1.254 [192.168.1.254] 22 (ssh): Operation timed out
```